# Why do I have a "TypeError: 'Command' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"?

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a management command to install some test data in a django app. One of my functions is giving me an error:

> TypeError: 'Command' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Here's the code that's causing it:

```
import string
from my_app.models import Customer
from random import choice

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def random_string(size=4, chars=string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits + "    "):
            """ Creates a random string of letters and digits """
            return ''.join(choice(chars) for _ in range(0, size))

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        c = Customer(firstname=self.random_string(), foo=bar)
```

If I do `pdb.set_trace()` at the point where `self.random_string()` is called, I note that I can't call `self.random_string()` but doing `''.join(choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(0, 4))` works fine.

What's going wrong there?

Full trace:

```
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/application/utils/management/commands/generate_test_data.py", line 263, in handle
    firstname=self.random_string(),
  File "/application/utils/management/commands/generate_test_data.py", line 64, in random_string
    return ''.join(choice(chars) for _ in range(0, size))
```

Comment: You forgot to declare the `self` argument for `random_string`.

Comment: It should be `def random_string(self,...)`..

Comment: (Since you didn't declare a `self` argument, Python is passing the `Command` instance as the `size` argument instead.)

Comment: Ugh, thanks. Completely forgot.